# Ways to refresh a page in browser

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Despite the fact that there are many similar topics in internet, there aren't any complete answer.

***What I want:***

Disable browser refreshing.

***What I know:***

As I know it isn't possible to hang listener on browser refresh event. So I have to hang listener on *keydown* event and block all possible variants of page reloading.

***Problem/What I don't know***

I can't imagine all possible variants for page reloading, and can neglect one of them. For example,
I can check:

- `event.keyCode == 116` //F5
- `event.keyCode == 82 && event.ctrlKey` // Ctrl + R

But in the same time there is Mac operation system when user can reload page with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> combination.

***Question/Request:***

***Provide me, please, a full list of ways for page reloading.***

*May be better ideas?*

Comment: Why would you ever block standard browser behaviour?

Comment: "What I want: Disable browser refreshing" — You can't. Solve the real problem instead. Make refreshing not cause a problem.

Comment: How about clicking the page refresh button? You can't stop that, since it's outside of your controllable window...

Comment: I need to block page refreshing since I use SPA and Backbone.js. It means that I should either block page reloading or invent a way how to redirect backbone's router to special URL on update

Comment: I don't see how using SPA or Backbone implies needing to block reloading. Generally state is preserved with fragments (`#`) in the URL bar, localStorage, or cookies (or some combination of those).

Comment: I use websockets and SPA. Each time you reload a page, websocket connection is broken. But backbone router navigate you to the same location, and as result try to send a request (or requests) to the server via broken connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really disabled browser refreshing. If nothing else works, i click the refresh-button beside my addressbar or just click at the end of the addressbar and press enter to reload the page - and you fortunately can't block that.

Please try to solve your real problem(s) instead - why should'n the user press resfresh? what goes wrong if he does? how can you work around that? Annoying the user (and this is what you're trying to do here) is never a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can show a notification to user on window.close event with a custom relevent message so that the user can stay on the page if she intends.